# SoundCloud Authentication issue with localhost

Tags: javascript, authentication, oauth-2.0, soundcloud

Javascript and SC API beginner here. I'm following this very basic example on the API page: https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/sdks#authentication

I realize this question has been asked before, but I've spent hours trying their (possibly outdated?) solutions and none of them have worked for me.

My problem is that the pop up window (callback.html) doesn't close. There is an error:

> Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin (assume there is a 'http://' in front ) 127.0.0.1 from accessing a frame with origin "null".The frame requesting access has a protocol of "http", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "file". Protocols must match

Am I correct in thinking that there are 2 problems here?

> 1. In the callback.html file, the window.opener.SC.connectCallback is returning null so the setTimeout() function cannot work
> 2. The callback.html file cannot be hosted on a local server in this way

So where can I host the callback.html file for development?
I've hosted the callback.html file on my local web server (in the folder C:\inetpub\wwwroot) and registered my app.

I've tried setting the redirect_uri to '127.0.0.1//callback.html' and 'localhost/callback.html', but both result in the same issue. Assume there is an 'http://' in front of both (SO won't let me post more than 2 links).

Here's my code:

```
SC.initialize({
    client_id: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    redirect_uri: "http://localhost/callback.html"
});
$(document).ready(function(){
    // initiate authentication popup
    $('#connectImg').on('click',function(){
         SC.connect(function() {
        // This gets the authenticated user's username
            SC.get('/me', function(me) { 
                alert('Hello, ' + me.username);
                console.log('Hello, ' + me.username);
            });
        });
    });
});
```